# When running a command via Paramiko exec_command it's adding some other data (\xe2\x80\x98/tmp/filename.txt\xe2\x80\x99)

Tags: python, character-encoding, sftp, paramiko, rhel7

I have a piece of code written in Python which uses Paramiko to run a command that copies a file from one place to another on a remote server. This has been working fine for the last two years. I tried it on a new OS today (RHEL 7.9) and it kept failing. I've been trying to debug the issue but keep hitting a wall. Following is the piece of code:

```py
dirpath = '/etc/somedir'
stdin, stdout, stderr = client.exec_command(f'sudo mv /tmp/filname.txt {dirpath}/filename.txt')
```

And the output

```
STDERR: ['mv: cannot move \xe2\x80\x98/tmp/filename.txt\xe2\x80\x99 to \xe2\x80\x98/etc/somedir/filename.txt\xe2\x80\x99: No such file or directory\\n'] ; 
STDOUT: []
```

I am using Paramiko 2.6.0, Python 3.6.3 and the remote machine is running RHEL 7.9. I am at my wits end with it and not able to find what's wrong, as it works fine on all other machines. I also couldn't find a similar question on stack overflow. There were similar question on other sites, but no one had answered them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code mislead you. The `\xe2\x80\x98`/`9` is UTF-8 for [left](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2018/index.htm)/[right single quote](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2019/index.htm). It's most likely a part of the error message formatting, not of the file name.

Your root problem is likely really what the error message says:

> No such file or directory

Check both the source and target paths.

---

If you do this, you should get the same error:

```
ssh user@host sudo mv /tmp/filname.txt /etc/somedir/filename.txt
```